# Angular Controller's Variable not being rendered in Template on declaring the controller in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<div ng-controller="CompetitionNavController as vm" style="position: relative" 
  ng-show="vm.is_authenticated" ng-click="vm.test();">
  {{ vm.authenticated_user }} User
</div>
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('sparro.nav.controllers')
    .controller('CompetitionNavController', CompetitionNavController);

  CompetitionNavController.$inject = ['$cookies', '$location', 
                                      '$localStorage', '$mdDialog', 
                                      '$rootScope', '$scope', 'Auth'];

  function CompetitionNavController($cookies, $location, $localStorage, 
                                    $mdDialog, $rootScope, $scope, Auth) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.is_authenticated = true;
    vm.authenticated_user = null;
    vm.test = test;

    activate();

    function activate() {
      vm.is_authenticated = isAuthenticated();
      vm.authenticated_user = $localStorage.user;

      $scope.staticUrl = staticUrl;
    }

    function isAuthenticated() {
      return Auth.isAuthenticated();
    }

    function test() {
      console.log('It works!');
    }
  }
})();
```

If I replace *ng-show* with *ng-if* in the template then the entire template doesn't load at all. If I click on the **User** text, it calls the proper function in the controller. I tried using $scope. Same results

What am I doing wrong? There is no error in the console as well.

Comment: provide a plunker

Comment: Off the top of my head: did you check whether isAuthenticated() returns what you expect (i.e. true) in the first place?

Comment: Please also call activate () as vm.activate() or this.activate()

Comment: @YanYankowski Yes isAuthenticated() returns proper value.